# Per user link limits the utility of StumbleUpon

Tags: discussion, publicity-badges

One of the more effective methods of promoting questions, especially on some of the "softer" sites is StumbleUpon.  StumbleUpon is a service that effectively allows you to say "Show me a web page I will like".

StumbleUpon tracks like (upvotes) by the page URL, so using your friendly question link, might actually limit the utility of StumbleUpon.  You get credit for sharing and a measure of tracking, but you lose the benefit of other people coming to the page organically and clicking the like button.

Is there any way to solve this problem so we get both the benefit of using our short links and the benefits of maximizing the StumbleUpon score?